# I have an error with logout in the stack laravel 8 / jetstream / inertiajs

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-jetstream, inertiajs

I'm trying to set a logout route.

I found a lot of blade syntax ([like that](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-fortify-and-logout)) but none with vuejs. So I tried to replicate the result of the blade syntax by inserting an input with the csrf token in value and the name set to "_token". (the csrf variable contains the string located in the XSRF-TOKEN cookie).

When I post, I have this error in console:
POST http: // localhost: 3000 / logout 419 (unknown status)

Can you tell me where my mistake is? How can I logout properly and be redirected to the page of my choice?

```
<form method="POST" :action="$route('logout')">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
   <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a better way to do it. I will share an idea with you.

### About the token

Share the token by the back-end to the front-end, as you did, isn't necessary.

### About the code in the Vue Component

The logout wasn't working because of your form.

#### Your form POST

```html
<form method="POST" :action="$route('logout')">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
   <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

#### The best way of form POST

```html
<form @submit.prevent="logout()">
   <button as="button" type="submit">
        Logout
   </button>
</form>
```

As you can see, when you submit the form it will call a method of the vue component called "logout". The method:

```js
export default{
    // Some code...
    
    methods:{
        logout() {
            this.$inertia.post(route('logout'));
        },
    }
}
```

Doing the logout process in this way, all the logical logout will be taken care of by the server-side. You will not have to worry about the token.

I hope it be useful for you. I also thank you because I just found this solution because of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

My error was on the recovery of the csrf token which was not good.
I would retrieve the long string contained in the XSRF-TOKEN cookie, while I had to receive the token from my backend. These 2 strings are strictly different, for some reason that I don't know yet.

I just needed to send the csrf token to my front-end with the csrf_token() method

```
return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
   'publications' => $publications,
   'users' => $users,
   'csrf_token' => csrf_token()
]);
```

I didn't need to do the form manually either

Finally, I was able to grab the token as a prop and include it in my post request like this:

```
this.$inertia.post('/logout', {
    _token: this.$props.csrf_token
})
```

[This link helped me](https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection)